# How to count number of occurrences within subgroup with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following `data.frame` (`dput()` at the end of question).

```
(c_arr_cords[1:20,])
   linkId       x       y vehicleRefId new_arr_time duration dep_time
1      90 2681090 1245442      1267069          0.0      6.5      6.5
2      90 2681090 1245442       532654         11.0      1.0     12.0
3      90 2681090 1245442      1398907         12.5      0.5     12.5
4      90 2681090 1245442      1267069         12.0     24.0     36.0
5      90 2681090 1245442         4205         16.5      0.0     16.5
6      90 2681090 1245442      1111105         11.0      0.0     11.5
7      90 2681090 1245442       434774         16.0      0.0     16.5
8      90 2681090 1245442      1179923          0.0     15.5     15.5
9      90 2681090 1245442        46491         14.5      0.5     15.0
10     90 2681090 1245442      1179923         16.0     19.5     36.0
11     90 2681090 1245442      1326473         11.0      3.0     13.5
12     90 2681090 1245442      1239391         13.0      0.5     13.5
13     90 2681090 1245442       810534          8.0      0.0      8.0
14     90 2681090 1245442        51825          9.5      0.5     10.0
15     90 2681090 1245442      1199672         11.0      1.0     12.0
16     90 2681090 1245442      1269433         17.5      1.5     19.0
17    389 2681367 1247844       492533         14.5      1.5     16.0
18    389 2681367 1247844      1454119         17.5     18.0     36.0
19    389 2681367 1247844      1278645          0.0      8.0      8.0
20    389 2681367 1247844      1430553         10.5      1.5     12.0
```

My goal is to create a `data.frame` where I see how many vehicles are on a `linkId` at any 1h time bin.
If a vehicle is on a link at time x can be derived from `new_arr_time` (arrival) and `dep_time` (departure). For `time = 12` (hour 12) on link 90, one has to count how many vehicles have their `new_arr_time <= 12` , and `dep_time >=12`. In total there will be maximum 48 time bins (if 0, it is not necessary to have a bin).

The desired table should have the following structure:

```
linkId  time    count
90      0.0     3
90      0.5     x
90      1.0     y
...
389     0.0     z
...
```

My struggle is to create an efficient loop to do this operation.

Thank you in advance!

Data:

```
structure(list(linkId = c(90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 
389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 
451L, 451L, 451L, 451L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 578L, 578L, 
578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 662L, 662L, 662L, 662L, 662L, 662L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L), x = c(2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 
2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 
2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 2681090, 2681366.83333333, 
2681366.83333333, 2681366.83333333, 2681366.83333333, 2681366.83333333, 
2681366.83333333, 2681366.83333333, 2681366.83333333, 2681366.83333333, 
2681366.83333333, 2681366.83333333, 2681366.83333333, 2681366.83333333, 
2681366.83333333, 2683684, 2683684, 2683684, 2683684, 2683675.34782609, 
2683675.34782609, 2683675.34782609, 2683675.34782609, 2683675.34782609, 
2676435, 2676435, 2676435, 2676435, 2676435, 2676435, 2676435, 
2682590, 2682590, 2682590, 2682590, 2682590, 2682590, 2672126, 
2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 
2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 
2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 
2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 
2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 
2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 
2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126, 2672126), y = c(1245442, 
1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 
1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 1245442, 
1245442, 1247843.75, 1247843.75, 1247843.75, 1247843.75, 1247843.75, 
1247843.75, 1247843.75, 1247843.75, 1247843.75, 1247843.75, 1247843.75, 
1247843.75, 1247843.75, 1247843.75, 1246790, 1246790, 1246790, 
1246790, 1246835.5, 1246835.5, 1246835.5, 1246835.5, 1246835.5, 
1241381, 1241381, 1241381, 1241381, 1241381, 1241381, 1241381, 
1237645.6, 1237645.6, 1237645.6, 1237645.6, 1237645.6, 1237645.6, 
1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 
1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 
1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 
1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 
1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 
1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 
1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783, 1248783), vehicleRefId = c(1267069L, 
532654L, 1398907L, 1267069L, 4205L, 1111105L, 434774L, 1179923L, 
46491L, 1179923L, 1326473L, 1239391L, 810534L, 51825L, 1199672L, 
1269433L, 492533L, 1454119L, 1278645L, 1430553L, 1412246L, 1533113L, 
1278645L, 1454119L, 1412246L, 1430553L, 1533113L, 1278645L, 1310775L, 
1310775L, 1161080L, 1290940L, 558745L, 628509L, 1530598L, 403850L, 
1397256L, 774916L, 3874L, 1043798L, 1881121L, 193835L, 526654L, 
2066556L, 1221124L, 12799L, 486288L, 485689L, 488147L, 485689L, 
486288L, 488147L, 2095866L, 42794L, 2149105L, 1887358L, 1902958L, 
1901830L, 1215125L, 2148165L, 1457624L, 1898426L, 1394390L, 1859644L, 
1908352L, 1885007L, 1885718L, 1887788L, 1222534L, 1888344L, 1926462L, 
1785664L, 2147547L, 1898186L, 1921295L, 1905635L, 1888247L, 1747951L, 
2149105L, 2821L, 1094609L, 1531804L, 1670344L, 1912658L, 1799420L, 
1908352L, 1925302L, 2064554L, 1887316L, 1869032L, 1925659L, 1794294L, 
1378838L, 1528492L, 4806833L, 5259385L, 1860654L, 1187619L, 1814856L, 
1863281L), new_arr_time = c(0, 11, 12.5, 12, 16.5, 11, 16, 0, 
14.5, 16, 11, 13, 8, 9.5, 11, 17.5, 14.5, 17.5, 0, 10.5, 18, 
13.5, 25, 0, 0, 12.5, 8.5, 17, 19, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 8.5, 
6, 13.5, 7.5, 14, 8, 10, 7.5, 18, 18, 9.5, 16, 18.5, 21, 0, 0, 
0, 18.5, 12, 19, 8, 9, 18, 14, 19, 10, 17, 12, 7, 13, 13.5, 11, 
14.5, 17, 9.5, 8.5, 8.5, 7, 6.5, 18.5, 22.5, 12.5, 18.5, 8, 14, 
6.5, 9.5, 8, 17.5, 17, 12.5, 8, 5.5, 18, 19.5, 7.5, 8.5, 13, 
18.5, 12, 15.5, 19, 20, 13, 8, 9.5), duration = c(6.5, 1, 0.5, 
24, 0, 0, 0, 15.5, 0.5, 19.5, 3, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 18, 
8, 1.5, 17.5, 5, 11, 7, 7, 0.5, 4, 2, 16.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 10, 
9.5, 10.5, 8, 8.5, 9.5, 8, 0.5, 0.5, 3, 1, 1, 2.5, 0, 17.5, 15, 
13, 7, 8, 17.5, 1, 3.5, 4.5, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2, 
4, 1, 2.5, 2, 2, 1, 0.5, 10, 10.5, 5, 0, 3.5, 0, 10.5, 3, 9.5, 
1.5, 0, 3, 2.5, 0, 3, 5.5, 1.5, 1, 10, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 
1, 2.5, 0.5), dep_time = c(6.5, 12, 12.5, 36, 16.5, 11.5, 16.5, 
15.5, 15, 36, 13.5, 13.5, 8, 10, 12, 19, 16, 36, 8, 12, 36, 18.5, 
36, 7, 7, 13, 12, 19.5, 36, 7.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17, 19, 14, 
22, 17, 22, 8.5, 11, 10, 19, 19, 12.5, 16.5, 36, 36, 13, 7, 8, 
36, 12.5, 22.5, 12.5, 11, 20, 15.5, 24, 10.5, 18, 12.5, 17, 14.5, 
17.5, 11.5, 17, 19, 12, 9.5, 9, 17, 17.5, 23.5, 22.5, 16.5, 18.5, 
19, 17, 16, 11, 8, 20.5, 19.5, 12.5, 11.5, 11, 19.5, 20.5, 17.5, 
9.5, 16, 18.5, 13, 16, 20.5, 22.5, 14, 10.5, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand it now better, here comes an approach based on an `outer` product and data mangling with package *tidyr*. It is more memory consuming than a loop, but also more compact:

```
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")

## half hour time slots
tm <- seq(0, 24, 0.5)

## Test if a value is in the interval. Please check manually with some examples.
## second version is more robust against IEEE floating point deviations
# fun <- function(i, x) (d[i, "new_arr_time"] <= x) & (x <= d[i, "dep_time"])
fun <- function(i, x) (d[i, "new_arr_time"] - x < 1e-6) & (x - d[i, "dep_time"] < 1e-6)

## outer creates all combinations between LinkIDs and time slots
expanded <- data.frame(outer(1:nrow(d), tm, fun))
names(expanded) <- tm

cbind(linkId=d$linkId, expanded) %>%
  pivot_longer(-linkId, names_to = "time", values_to = "count") %>%
  group_by(linkId, time) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(count))
```

To understand what the individual steps in the `%>%`pipeline do, rebuild the pipe from scratch and add one line after each other.

Comment: struggled with it for the longest, until i realized a package collision. ```dplyr::summarize(count = sum(count))``` solved the issue. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean with:

> have their new_arr_time <= 12 , and dep_time >=12

but if we assume, just for example, that it is enough to use duration (or another calculated value), one can do such an aggregation without any loop with `aggregate` in R base or with package **dplyr**:

```
d %>% group_by(linkId, duration) %>% summarize(count = n())
```

or with "base R" (without **dplyr**):

```
with(d, aggregate(list(count = linkId), list(linkId = linkId, duration=duration), length))
```

Comment: What I meant was, in this example, that the arrival time has to be before 12 and the departure after 12. Thank you for your example. I believe though it does not deliver the desired result. I have to know how many vehicles are at a certain time at a link. Your code tells me how many stop for how long at a link, but not if they are there at the same time.

Comment: Why I wondered is what you mean with "30 min time bin" and then "12". Are the latter hours? Is there a (limited) set of "bins"? 48?

Comment: I changed it into hourly bins, to make it perhaps a bit easier to understand. It wasn't clear before.